# Обратный scroll

Tags: прокрутка

Используя:

```
<div style="overflow-y: scroll;">
   ... ... ...
</div>
```

получается стандартный скроллинг (сверху вниз), можно сделать наоборот, что бы содержимое отображалось с низу в верх?

Answer (score 1):

Можна сделать, чтоб при загрузке страници блок твой автоматически проскролился вниз. Вот для этого скрипт:

```js
document.querySelector('.content> .content__item:last-child').scrollIntoView(true);
```

```css
.wrap {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">
    <p class='content__item'>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem</p>
    <p class='content__item'>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem</p>
    <p class='content__item'>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem</p>
    <p class='content__item'>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem</p>
    <p class='content__item'>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem</p>
    <p class='content__item'>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem</p>
    <p class='content__item'>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem</p>
    <p class='content__item'>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem</p>
    <p class='content__item'>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem</p>
    <p class='content__item'>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem</p>
    <p class='content__item'>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, случайно подгрузил jquery, она тут не нужна.